# Collision handling doesn't work in iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm currently trying to get along with the collision handling in Xcode 11 (iOS 13).
My problem is that not even Apple's example code seems to work for me.
(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/about_collisions_and_contacts)

Example code from Apple:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        let ballRadius: CGFloat = 20
        let redBall = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: ballRadius)
        redBall.fillColor = .red
        redBall.position = CGPoint(x: 280, y: 320)
        redBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ballRadius)

        let blueBall = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: ballRadius)
        blueBall.fillColor = .blue
        blueBall.position = CGPoint(x: 360, y: 320)
        blueBall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ballRadius)

        var splinePoints = [CGPoint(x: 0, y: 300),
                            CGPoint(x: 100, y: 50),
                            CGPoint(x: 400, y: 110),
                            CGPoint(x: 640, y: 20)]
        let ground = SKShapeNode(splinePoints: &splinePoints,
                                 count: splinePoints.count)
        ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeChainFrom: ground.path!)
        ground.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.75

        redBall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0b0001
        blueBall.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0b0010
        ground.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0b0001        

    }




    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered
    }
}
```

When i run the code, both balls collide with the curve.

Is there something I did wrong or is there an updated functionality within SpriteKit I don't know about?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: When I run this on iOS 13 (and add the red ball, blue ball, and ground to the scene using `addChild(_:)`) the blue ball passes through the curve as expected. You may need to show more code for us to help you further.

Comment: My code is the same as the one above, except the fact that I added the nodes to scene with:
    self.addChild(redBall)
And so on ..

Is there any chance that one of the other default project files contain any issues?

Answer (score 1):

I created a new Xcode project and pasted the code from the question and it eventually worked.

I don't know which of the project files was causing the issue.

Thanks for the help!